# libblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (but it is installed)

Tags: c++, docker, linker

I'm building a c++ app on Docker using multi-staging build. When I run my executable in the 2nd stage, I get the following error:

```
./runScenarioTest: error while loading shared libraries: libblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, when I go check my /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ directory, I can cleary see that `libblas.a` `libblas.so` `libblas.so.3` are there. However, they seem to be the only libraries to appear in red text when I run the `ls` command inside the directory. I looked for the meaning of red text and I believe it because they are stored as file archive (?).

I am running this on a Ubuntu:20.04 base image, and I am installing the BLAS and Lapack packages through libatlas-base-dev (`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev`)

I then copy the whole /lib/ folder from the build stage to the run stage.

My question: Is it normal for theses files to appear in red text and is it related to the fact that they can't be found at run-time? Thanks in advance

I tried installing the BLAS and Lapack packages separatly:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libblas-dev

RUN apt-get install -y liblapack-dev
```

I also tried adding this line right before building

```
RUN /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

Comment: And what does `ls -al` show you?

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     44 Feb 10 14:54 libblas.a -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.a-x86_64-linux-gnu`
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     45 Feb 10 14:54 libblas.so -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so-x86_64-linux-gnu`
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     47 Feb 10 14:54 libblas.so.3 -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: And where does each symbolic link points to, does that file exists? Do you know what symbolic links are, and how they work?

Comment: I am not completely sure on how they work, however, I can tell you that when I run `ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3`
I get the following output
`ldd: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3: No such file or directory`

Can I provide you with more info to help?

Comment: The symbolic link is broken. At this time, my general advice would be: before getting involved with highly specialized, technical subjects like dockers and containers it makes much more sense to invest a little bit of time in educating about basic, fundamental concepts about how files and directories work on Linux, what are hard links, symbolic links, the difference between them, etc... These subjects should be covered in every introductory Linux textbook. Attempting to dive into containers, docker, etc..., before having a solid grasp on these fundamentals will not be very productive.

Comment: I understand. I am really trying to learn more basics but it's hard to learn everything in the right order and still be productive.

I ran ls -l and figured out that the symlink points to etc/alternatives which wasn't copied from the build stage to run stage.

Thanks. 

I read too fast about the LS color doc and was lead the wrong way:

Red: Archive file
Red with black background: Broken link

Comment: Colors on a terminal screen are not an ultimate authority and judge. Additionally, different terminals may use different colors. The only thing that matters is what each file actually is.